# Wrong result for a $1^\infty$ limit

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I wanna know the $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x)^x .$$
I applied $1^\infty$ algorithm and I have in last sentence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{2x+4-\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}\right)^x.$$ After that I used $x=e^{\ln x}$ and got this: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{x^2+4x-x\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}\right).$$ The result for this, I think is $2$, but I'm not really sure of this, Wolfram-Alpha says that it's $\frac{3}{2}$. Can explain somebody why, but without L'Hospital?

Thks a lot!

Comment: "I used $x=e^{\ln(x)}$ and got this: " How? This is very likely where mistakes crept in.

Comment: The limit seems to be $\large e^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt,  I'm pretty sure of that: http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Ln.htm

Comment: @Peter, can you give an explanation, please?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, yeah, u are right, it's e^lim()

Comment: @arcilli Your link does nothing to explain what you've done here....

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I used that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/x)^x=e$, and I transfered the limit at the exponent

Comment: That is still far from an explanation of what you've done. Please [edit] your question instead. (Note you probably made a mistake, since what you have obviously doesn't equal 3/2, so...)

Comment: I don't know how important its the title of the question since I'm here. Obviously, we're all here for math answers, not for 100% explicit titles.

Comment: I think the title is fine, though the "Thks a lot!" can be [removed/unnecessary](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/why-do-we-need-to-avoid-to-thank-somebody?rq=1). Indeed, your question is, at the moment, unanswerable I would say, as you ask for why it is wrong but you still haven't explained why/how you got to that last limit.

Comment: To calculate the limit at the bottom of your question (which is $\frac{3}{2}$), consider $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x(1-\sqrt{1+2/x+4/x^2})=-1$$ In order to calculate this limit , substitute $z=1/x$ and consider the taylor-expansion of $\frac{\sqrt{1+2z+4z^2}}{z}$

Comment: Your approach was fine!

Comment: @Peter, in the last I have $(\frac{x^2(1-\sqrt{1+2x/x+4/x^2})+4x}{x(\sqrt{1+2x^2+4/x^2}+1}))$ and I cant figure it out from where 3/2. I consider that x^2(1-sqrt(...)) it's 0 and I have 4x/2x=2. Tell me whre I am wrong

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $x$, then apply the hint in my second comment. Your error was to cancel out $x$ against the square root which gives $2$ at the end.

Comment: I actually think proper grammar, punctuation, and phrasing matters a lot in titles. When people are making searches about a topic instead of the ask a new question search, if they type "definition" they can't find "definiton" or "defintion" also titles can be a source of confusion at times/ misleading. think about things like combinations with or without replacement etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes WA gives  absolutely wrong results, but in our case he gave a right answer.

Since $f(x)=e^x$ is a continuous function, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x)^x =\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{2x+4}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}\right)^x =$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{2x+4}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{2x+4}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}-1}\cdot x\left(\frac{2x+4}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}-1\right)} =$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x\left(\frac{2x+4}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}-1\right)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x( x+4-\sqrt{x^2+2x+4})}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x(6x+12)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+x\right)\left( x+4+\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}\right)}}=e^{\frac{6}{2\cdot2}}=e^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is evaluated with  *Taylor's formula* at order $2$:
$$\ln\Bigl(\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x\bigr)^x\Bigr)=x\ln\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x\bigr)=x\Bigl(\ln x+\ln\biggl(\sqrt{1+\frac2x+\frac4{x^2}}-1\biggr)\biggr).
$$
Now, Taylor's expansion at order $2$ yields
\begin{align}\sqrt{1+\frac2x+\frac4{x^2}}-1&=1+\frac12\biggl(\frac2x+\frac4{x^2}\biggr)-\frac18\biggl(\frac2x+\frac4{x^2}\biggr)^2+o\biggl(\frac1{x^2}\biggr)-1\\
&=\frac1x+\frac3{2x^2}+o\biggl(\frac1{x^2}\biggr)=\frac1x\biggl(1+\frac3{2x}+o\biggl(\frac1{x}\biggr)\biggr),\end{align}
so that
$$\ln\biggl(\sqrt{1+\frac2x+\frac4{x^2}}-1\biggr)=-\ln x+\ln\biggl(1+\frac3{2x}+o\biggl(\frac1{x}\biggr)\biggr)=-\ln x+\frac3{2x}+o\biggl(\frac1{x}\biggr),$$
and finally
$$\ln\Bigl(\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x\bigr)^x\Bigr)=x\biggl(\ln x-\ln x+\frac3{2x}+o\biggl(\frac1{x}\biggr)\biggr)=\frac32+o(1)\to\frac32.$$

Comment: The actual answer is $e^{3/2}$. How do you reconcile the minus sign in your answer?

Comment: I think I'll have to check my computation… :o(

Comment: @imranfat: I found no error in my computation, However, I don't where the numerator in the O.P.'s computation comes from. I only used the original expression.

Comment: $\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac18 \frac{4}{x^2} = \frac{2}{x^2}- \frac{1}{2x^2}=\frac{3}{2x^2}$.

Comment: @martycohen: Oh! yes, of course. How did I manage not to see it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Want
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x)^x
$.

Since,
for small $z$,
$\sqrt{1+z}
=1+\frac12 z + O(z^2)
$
and
$\ln(1+z)
=z+O(z^2)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}
&=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+3}\\
&=(x+1)\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{(x+1)^2}}\\
&=(x+1)(1+\frac{3}{2(x+1)^2}+O(x^{-4}))\\
&=x+1+\frac{3}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-3})\\
\text{so}\\
\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x
&=1+\frac{3}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-3})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\ln(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x)
=\ln(1+\frac{3}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-3}))
=\frac{3}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-2})
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
x\ln(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x)
&=\frac{3x}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-1})\\
&=\frac{3(x+1)-3}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-1})\\
&=\frac32-\frac{3}{2(x+1)}+O(x^{-1})\\
&=\frac32+O(x^{-1})\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-x)^x
=e^{3/2}
$.